# Pandas Filter by string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to filter my groups to show only the groups that contain a string in all the rows of a group.

```
Index  A   B   C    
0      A1  B5  T    
1      A1  B2  T    
2      A1  B2  F    
3      A2  B5  T    
4      A2  F5  T    
5      A3  F4  T    
6      A4  F4  F
```

Returns:

```
Index  A   B   C   
3      A2  B5  T   
4      A2  F5  T   
5      A3  F4  T
```

Tried: `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x[x['C']==T])`

And as you may have known it returns:

```
Index  A   B   C   
0      A1  B5  T   
1      A1  B2  T   
3      A2  B5  T   
4      A2  F5  T   
5      A3  F4  T
```

When I change apply to filter I get an error.

Help Please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `transform`**
*Fastest solution that is also simple*

```
df[df.C.eq('T').groupby(df.A.values).transform('all')]

        A   B  C
Index           
3      A2  B5  T
4      A2  F5  T
5      A3  F4  T
```

---

**Using `crosstab`**
*Shortest solution I could think of... but slow*

```
df[df.A.map(pd.crosstab(df.A, df.C).F.eq(0))]

        A   B  C
Index           
3      A2  B5  T
4      A2  F5  T
5      A3  F4  T
```

---

**`project`/*kill***
*Very fast solution... but complicated*

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.A.values)
t = (df.C.values == 'T').astype(int)
b0 = np.bincount(f * 2 + t)
pad = np.zeros(2 * u.size - b0.size, dtype=int)
b = np.append(b0, pad)

df[~b.reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0].astype(bool)[f]]

        A   B  C
Index           
3      A2  B5  T
4      A2  F5  T
5      A3  F4  T
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df[df.C.eq('T').groupby(df.A.values).transform('all')]
%timeit df[df.A.map(pd.crosstab(df.A, df.C).F.eq(0))]
%timeit df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x[x.C=='T'])==len(x))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.67 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.15 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.05 ms per loop

%%timeit
f, u = pd.factorize(df.A.values)
t = (df.C.values == 'T').astype(int)
b0 = np.bincount(f * 2 + t)
pad = np.zeros(2 * u.size - b0.size, dtype=int)
b = np.append(b0, pad)

df[~b.reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0].astype(bool)[f]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop

d1 = df.assign(mydummy=df['C']=='T')
d1['mysum'] = d1.groupby('A').mydummy.transform('sum')
d1['mycount'] = d1.groupby('A').mysum.transform('size')
d1.loc[d1.mysum == d1.mycount, df.columns]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.68 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

try this little fella

```
df['mydummy'] = x['C']== T
df['mysum'] = df.groupby('A').mydummy.transform('sum')
df['mycount'] = df.groupby('A').mysum.transform('size')
df = df.loc[mysum == mycount]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter after groupby to check if all rows in the groups have T in column C.

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x[x.C=='T'])==len(x))
Out[41]: 
  Index   A   B  C
3     3  A2  B5  T
4     4  A2  F5  T
5     5  A3  F4  T
```